# preg_match specific pattern containing - (hyphen) in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i want to `preg_match` a string that looks like this(below), i've tried other methods but they work for specific string not both

`firstname`

`first-name`

and apart from that, reject the other string

i tried doing it, but unable to do, and i figured out, it's only possible with regex, and since i don't know anything about regex, i cannot do it in a minute or so and run a vulnerable code, do we have anyother way to do it, if not regex

Comment: There are some Tools like https://www.regex101.com/ that help you ´to Build and test RegExpressions

Comment: You shouldn't use regular expressions al all unless you know how they work and the usage of the functions that invoke them. Certainly not in code that cannot be tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^\w+-?\w+$/', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match 0 or 1 hyphens with the `?` symbol:

```
if( preg_match('/^first-?name$/', $yourString ) ){
    // matched.
}
```

The `^` and `$` symbols are start and end markers, added to ensure the string is exact.

Comment: first-name, firstname was just an example :)

Comment: Fair enough, but you did write "apart from that, reject the other string". If there were other criteria for what should be matched then you needed to specify. The answer you accepted will also match `"__"` and `"___"` as valid strings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.regex101.com/

try
    `(first[\-]{0,1}name)`

works fine :-)

php code :

```
$pattern = '(first[\-]{0,1}name)';
echo preg_match($pattern,'firstname');

echo preg_match($pattern,'first-name');
```

outputs: `11` - that means true - true